# one button to refresh multiple iframes on iframe name

Tags: button, iframe

Dear stackoverflow users,

I have the following code:

```
    <button onclick="var ifr=document.getElementsByName('menuframe')[0]; ifr.src=ifr.src;">Refresh Iframes</button>
```

And this code only changes the first iframe. I have tried changing the [0] to [1] and this lets me refresh the second iframe but not the first.

So i tried [0-10] but that did not do anything. Also i tried [0,1] but this changed the second.

I know it must be possible but how. I have no idea. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I figured I'd throw an answer.

To start I would recommend calling a function in the onclick attribute instead of including inline javascript. You would accomplish this using the following:

```
<button onclick="javascript:refreshIframes('menuFrame');">Refresh Iframes</button>
```

I added a variable to the function to allow it to be reusable for other iframe names.

In your page (most people prefer to place it at the bottom, some prefer to place it in an external javascript file that is then referenced) you would include a function similar to the following:

```
function refreshIframes(frameName) {
    var frames = document.getElementsByName(frameName);
    for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
        var frame = frames[i];
        frame.src = frame.src;
    }
}
```

If you decide to include this on your page instead of putting it inside an external javascript file you would need to wrap it in script tags.